# Equation of the curve corresponding to a principal polarization

Tags: algebraic-geometry, riemann-surfaces, abelian-varieties, theta-functions

Let $\mathbb{C}^2/\Lambda$ be a principally polarized abelian surface. I think it is well-known how to write down the equation of the divisor (Riemann surface) corresponding to the polarization, in terms of theta functions etc. Could anyone kindly give me a reference for this?